# swagger 2.0 host format, Flask, Python, REST-API

Tags: python, rest, flask, swagger

This is my code:

```
from pathlib import Path
from main_functions.CLI import main_cli
from flask import Flask, request, render_template, jsonify
from flask_restful import Api, Resource, reqparse
from flasgger import Swagger, swag_from
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)
swagger = Swagger(app)

parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
parser.add_argument('version', type=int, help='API version', required=True)
parser.add_argument('format', type=str, help='Response format (JSON, XML)', required=True)


class ReportResource(Resource):
    @swag_from('swagger.yml')
    def get(self):
        version = int(request.args.get('version'))
        format = request.args.get('format')

        if version == 1:
            best_racers, invalid_racers = main_cli(files=Path("data"), sort_order=None)
            if format == 'JSON':
                return jsonify({"best_racers": best_racers, "invalid_racers": invalid_racers})
            elif format == 'XML':
                root = ET.Element("RaceData")

                best_racers_element = ET.Element("BestRacers")
                for racer_key, (formatted_time, full_name, team) in best_racers.items():
                    racer_element = ET.Element("Racer")
                    formatted_time_element = ET.Element("FormattedTime")
                    formatted_time_element.text = formatted_time
                    full_name_element = ET.Element("FullName")
                    full_name_element.text = full_name
                    team_element = ET.Element("Team")
                    team_element.text = team
                    racer_element.append(formatted_time_element)
                    racer_element.append(full_name_element)
                    racer_element.append(team_element)
                    best_racers_element.append(racer_element)

                invalid_racers_element = ET.Element("InvalidRacers")
                for racer_key, (error_message, full_name, team) in invalid_racers.items():
                    racer_element = ET.Element("Racer")
                    error_message_element = ET.Element("ErrorMessage")
                    error_message_element.text = error_message
                    full_name_element = ET.Element("FullName")
                    full_name_element.text = full_name
                    team_element = ET.Element("Team")
                    team_element.text = team
                    racer_element.append(error_message_element)
                    racer_element.append(full_name_element)
                    racer_element.append(team_element)
                    invalid_racers_element.append(racer_element)

                root.append(best_racers_element)
                root.append(invalid_racers_element)

                xml_data = ET.tostring(root, encoding='utf-8')

                response = app.response_class(
                    response=xml_data,
                    status=200,
                    mimetype='application/xml'
                )

                return response

        else:
            return "Unsupported API version"


api.add_resource(ReportResource, '/api/v1/report/')


@app.route('/api/report')
def show_common_report():
    best_racers, invalid_racers = main_cli(files=Path("data"), sort_order=None)
    return render_template('common_report.html', best_racers=best_racers, invalid_racers=invalid_racers)


@app.route('/api/report/drivers')
def show_report():
    order = request.args.get('order', 'asc')
    best_racers, invalid_racers = main_cli(files=Path("data"), sort_order=order)
    return render_template('ordered_report.html', best_racers=best_racers, invalid_racers=invalid_racers)


@app.route('/api/report/driver')
def show_driver():
    driver_id = request.args.get('driver_id')
    best_racers, invalid_racers = main_cli(files=Path("data"), driver_name=driver_id)
    if not driver_id:
        return ("Usege: /report/driver?driver_id=SVF")
    return render_template('driver_report.html', best_racers=best_racers, invalid_racers=invalid_racers)


@app.route('/api/driver_list')
def show_driver_list():
    data = main_cli(files=Path("data"), list_drivers=True)
    return render_template('driver_list.html', data=data)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

and yml file

```
---
swagger: '2.0'
info:
  version: '1.0'
  title: Race Report API
  description: API for accessing race report data
host: 127.0.0.1:5000
basePath: /api
schemes:
  - http
tags:
  - name: Report
    description: API operations for generating race reports
paths:
  /api/v1/report/:
    get:
      tags:
        - Report
      summary: Get Race Report
      description: This endpoint returns a race report based on version and format.
      parameters:
        - name: version
          in: query
          type: integer
          required: true
          description: API version (e.g., 1)
        - name: format
          in: query
          type: string
          required: true
          description: Response format (JSON, XML)
      responses:
        '200':
          description: Successful response
          schema:
            type: object
            properties:
              best_racers:
                type: object
                description: Best racers data
              invalid_racers:
                type: object
                description: Invalid racers data
        '400':
          description: Bad Request
    parameters:
      - name: version
        in: query
        type: integer
        required: true
        description: API version (e.g., 1)
      - name: format
        in: query
        type: string
        required: true
        description: Response format (JSON, XML)
  /api/report:
    get:
      tags:
        - Report
      summary: Show Common Report
      description: This endpoint renders a common HTML report.
      responses:
        '200':
          description: Successful response
    parameters:
      - name: order
        in: query
        type: string
        required: false
        description: Order for the report (asc, desc)
  /api/report/drivers:
    get:
      tags:
        - Report
      summary: Show Report
      description: This endpoint renders an ordered HTML report.
      responses:
        '200':
          description: Successful response
    parameters:
      - name: order
        in: query
        type: string
        required: false
        description: Order for the report (asc, desc)
  /api/report/driver:
    get:
      tags:
        - Report
      summary: Show Driver Report
      description: This endpoint renders an HTML report for a specific driver.
      responses:
        '200':
          description: Successful response
    parameters:
      - name: driver_id
        in: query
        type: string
        required: false
        description: Driver ID (e.g., SVF)
  /api/driver_list:
    get:
      tags:
        - Report
      summary: Show Driver List
      description: This endpoint renders a list of drivers in HTML.
      responses:
        '200':
          description: Successful response
```

I can't understand what I'm doing wrong. On the first screenshot, my browser/site is shown, and on the second, the OpenAPI preview. Is the spelling correct?

[image: 1st]

[image: 2d]

I tried to find information about the correct formatting of a YAML file, but apparently, I'm doing something wrong